# Fade JPG image to transparency using CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have a solid image, a `.JPG`, with no transparency (seeing as `.JPG`'s cannot have an alpha layer).  However, since the client would not have the ability to create an image that fades one image edge to transparency, they want to input a solid `.JPG` and have it fade via code.  It should be noted that I've got this image set to be the `background` right now, it's not the `src` of a `<img>` tag.  Is this possible in CSS3 and if so, how would it be accomplished?

**Example image:**

[image: SOLID JPG]

**Desired result:**

[image: FADED PNG]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do something with the *CSS3* [`mask-image`](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/) attribute along with CSS3 `linear-gradient` background:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0))
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/RGL3b/) is a sample that I created to you. Since it's a new *CSS3* thing compatible browsers are Chrome and Safari at this moment (*Webkit browsers*).

Answer (score 2):

You can get true transparency via CSS masking:

http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/

Support for it is still quite limited, though. However, in Webkit browsers, you can use something like:

```
.masked {
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
}

<div class="masked">Your content here</div>
```

This will work with all the content in any div (including the background), but this won't work in most browsers.

You could use a slice-and-animate approach similar to [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/), but that is an awful lot of work for what may not end up being a useful effect.

Comment: Chris, your answer was indeed correct, but ErickPetru answered before you.  Apologies, but I greatly appreciate your answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
img,.over{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
position:absolute;
}​


<div  >
<img src="http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=I.4763892546143716&pid=1.1" alt="test"/>
<div class="over"></div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/fSJAu/)